# Merging a bunch of csv files into one with headers

Tags: r, list, csv, merge

I have a couple of csv files I want to combine as a list then output as one merged csv. Suppose these files are called file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv, etc...

```
file1.csv     # example of what each might look like
V1 V2 V3 V4
12 12 13 15
14 12 56 23
```

How would I create a list of these csvs so that I can output a merged csv that would have headers as the file names and the column names at the top as comments? So a csv that would look something like this in Excel:

```
# 1: V1
# 2: V2
# 3: V3
# 4: V4

file1.csv
12 12 13 15
14 12 56 23

file2.csv
12 12 13 15
14 12 56 23

file3.csv
12 12 13 15
14 12 56 23
```

I am trying to use the `list` function inside of a double for loop to merge these csvs together, write each list to a variable, and write each variable to a table output. however this does not not work as intended.

```
# finding the correct files in the directory
files <- dir("test files/shortened")
files_filter <- files[grepl("*\\.csv", files)]
levels <- unique(gsub( "-.*$", "", files_filter))

# merging
for(i in 1:length(levels)){
  level_specific <- files_filter[grepl(levels[i], files_filter)]
  bindme
  for(j in 1:length(level_specific)){
    bindme2 <- read.csv(paste("test files/shortened/",level_specific[j],sep=""))
    bindme <- list(bindme,bindme2)
    assign(levels[i],bindme)
  }
  write.table(levels[i],file = paste(levels[i],"-output.csv",sep=""),sep=",")
}
```

Comment: If all the files have the same structure, you could just use `rbindlist` from the `data.table` package.

Comment: How should I use rbindlist with a for loop? I was thinking about putting it in the first for loop before the write.table line, however I don't know how I would call each data.table that was generated by the second for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think you don't need a for-loop. With the `data.table` package you could do it as follows:

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
files <- lapply(filenames, fread) # fread is the fast reading function from the data.table package
merged_data <- rbindlist(files)
write.csv(merged_data, file="merged_data_file.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

If at least one of the `csv`s has column names set, they will be used in the resulting datatable.

---

Considering your code, it could be improved considerably. This:

```
files <- dir("test files/shortened")
files_filter <- files[grepl("*\\.csv", files)]
```

can be replaced by just:

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
```

In your for-loop the first time you call `bindme`, it isn't doing anything. What is it? A list? A dataframe? You could use something like:

```
bindme <- data.table() # or data.frame()
```

Furthermore, the part:

```
write.table(levels[i],file = paste(levels[i],"-output.csv",sep=""),sep=",")
```

will generate several `csv`-files, but you wanted just one merged file.

Answer (score 2):

Would this help

---

```
mergeMultipleFiles <- function(dirPath, nameRegex, outputFilename){
  filenames <- list.files(path=dirPath, pattern=nameRegex, full.names=TRUE, recursive=T)
  dataList <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, header=T, check.names=F)
  combinedData <- ldply(dataList, rbind)
  write.csv(combinedData, outputFilename)
}
```

---

ps: There is a regex thrown in for filenames. Just in case you want to only merge certain "pattern" of files.

Answer (score 1):

Modify this example. If I understood your question correctly it will help you.

```
# get the names of the csv files in your current directory
    file_names = list.files(pattern = "[.]csv$")  

# for every name you found go and read the csv with that name 
# (this creates a list of files)
    import_files = lapply(file_names, read.csv)

# append those files one after the other (collapse list elements to one dataset) and save it as d
    d=do.call(rbind, import_files)
```